# Como obter o código HTML de uma página com PHP?

Tags: php

Estou em um projeto em que preciso obter o HTML de uma determinada página na web para poder verificar o conteúdo do HTML dessa página. Poderiam que caminho eu posso seguir para fazer tal ação em PHP?

Atualmente estou usando o `file_get_contents()` porém quando dou `echo` no conteúdo ele me retorna o conteúdo já formatado. Quero ler exatamente o código fonte.

Comment: O `file_get_contents` está te dando o fonte, ele só aparece formatado porque você está dando `echo`.

Comment: É como diz o @bfavaretto.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Olá! Na verdade o `file_get_contents()` faz exatamente o que você quer!

> **Do manual PHP:** `file_get_contents()` — Lê todo o conteúdo de um arquivo para uma string.

**Isto é:** `file_get_contents()` não interpreta o arquivo, só lê e volta exatamente o que está escrito nele, sem processar nada; retornando exatamente o conteúdo do arquivo quando leu.

**O problema:** quando você executa o `echo` no código resgatado, ele acaba de qualquer forma sendo imprimido na página, ou seja, direto na marcação HTML do documento e assim o navegador interpretará o código fonte que você obteve, no caso ele irá ler as tags.

**A solução:** na verdade você está fazendo tudo certinho, logo, **não precisa de solução**. Se você quer ler o código fonte na página, tem que usar caracteres imprimíveis, ou seja, trocar código de marcação "`< > &`" por "`&lt; &gt; &amp;`". Por sorte o PHP faz isso com uma função nativa `htmlentities()`.

Sobre a `htmlentities()`:

```
<?php
$str = "<© W3Sçh°°¦§>";
echo htmlentities($str);
?>
```

O HTML imprimido na página será:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
&lt;&copy; W3S&ccedil;h&deg;&deg;&brvbar;&sect;&gt;
</body>
</html>
```

No navegador, será interpretado e exibido na página como:

```
<© W3Sçh°°¦§>
```

Mais sobre o `htmlentities()`:

- http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlentities.asp
- http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: Não sei se é bem isso que ele quer...

Comment: "preciso obter o HTML de uma determinada página na web", `file_get_contents` faz exatamente isso, ele só deve estar se atrapalhando com o fato que que ao tentar depurar o resultado da função, não vê nenhum HTML, porém com essa explicação acho que ele conseguirá entender.

Comment: @JorgeB. Se por outro lado você acha que parece uma boa pergunta canônica para responder "use curl etc etc etc", eu pensei nisso. Mas bateu na trave...

Comment: @bfavaretto eu ando aqui a testar desde então e também ainda não cheguei a lado nenhum ;) 
Acho que a melhor resposta é mesmo a do Machado.